# Unexpected error while processing request: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, thin

I have a Bitnami Rails stack using Ubuntu.  I'm setting up Nginx with 5 Thin web application servers.  When I try to access my Rails app via a browser, it looks like Nginx is sending the request onto the Thin servers.  But, I get "Internal server error" back in the browser.

The thin.3000.log then contains these entries:

```
>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 127.0.0.1:3000, CTRL+C to stop
!! Unexpected error while processing request: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
!! Unexpected error while processing request: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Does this mean some sort of DNS problem?

This is my thin.yml = https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35302780/thin.yml

This is my nginx.conf = https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35302780/nginx.conf

And this is the ndeavor.conf that get included with nginx.conf = https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35302780/ndeavor.conf

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

Even if I just run Thin in stand-alone, I'm getting the same error.

```
bitnami@linux:/opt/bitnami/projects/ndeavor/current$ thin -e production start
>> Using rack adapter
/opt/bitnami/projects/ndeavor/releases/20130314191109/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.

[DEVISE] Devise.use_salt_as_remember_token is deprecated and has no effect. Please remove it.

>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
!! Unexpected error while processing request: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a DNS server that was down.